# Deploy a web app from a docker image on IBM cloud

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I have a docker image with a web application inside, I am looking for a service in IBM Cloud that enables users to deploy the web application using an image present in the container registry. Microsoft Azure provides a service call `Web app` and I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use a full Kubernetes cluster to deploy Docker images or push them to the Cloud Foundry environments ([Public](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-foundry-public?topic=cloud-foundry-public-hosting_apps) or Enterprise Environment). See here for some [instructions on how push Docker image to Cloud Foundry as part of the Logistics Wizard demo](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/logistics-wizard/blob/master/Deploy_Microservices_Cloud_Foundry_Docker.md).